# WKWebView on Swift not running die() on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to turn my PWA into an app. So far I have got every part to work, except for Google Sign-in.

I use PHP to verify the token given from Google OAuth2 and then send it over as postMessage.

```
if($userinfo) { // check if the token was validated successfully
  print_r($userinfo);
  $_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo['sub'];
  die("<script>window.opener.postMessage({sid: '".session_id()."'}, '*')</script>");
} else {
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Invalid Token');
  die("Invalid token (try signing in again)");
}
```

When this runs on WKWebView, it only runs `print_r` on the userinfo and doesn't die and run the script that posts the `sid`.

How do you make php in die when running in Webview?

Thank you very much.